# How fontawesome work with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, font-awesome, jsx

I installed react-create-app with npm and with npm I installed react-fontawesome. But how I can include css styles of fontawesome in my project?

My work space
[image: my work space]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably at the moment `react-icons` is the best way of including FA icons into your app, as it only brings in those icons, which are used in your project, not all the icon sheet

https://gorangajic.github.io/react-icons/

```
import FaBeer from 'react-icons/fa/beer';

class Question extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h3> Lets go for a <FaBeer />? </h3>
    }
}
```

P.S. to answer your question..

this is what the docs of your `react-fontawesome` say

> The fastest way to get started is to import FontAwesome with a link
>   tag in your page's :

```
 <link
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
 rel="stylesheet" />
```